# MemberShip Create Role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, role-manager

*Additional information:*

> An error occurred while attempting to initialize a
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was
>   provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an
>   invalid syntax.

I'm creation new `role` in my web application. When i add new role i got an `error` i don't have any idea about it kindly help me.

*Connection string :*

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PayRollContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PayRollDataModel.csdl|res://*/PayRollDataModel.ssdl|res://*/PayRollDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ATI_SHAH\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PayRollManagmentSystem;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

`Controller` where i get an error here: `{var chkRole = Roles.RoleExists(rolename);}`

```
public ActionResult CreatRole(aspnet_Roles role)
{
    string rolename = role.RoleName;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var chkRole = Roles.RoleExists(rolename);
        if (chkRole == true)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "* Role Already Exist");
        }
        else
        {
            Roles.CreateRole(rolename);
            return RedirectToAction("ListRole", "Role");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the data in there (the metadata, etc.) is just confusing SQL Server.

```
<add name="PayRollContext" connectionString="data source=ATI_SHAH\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PayRollManagmentSystem;multipleactiveresultsets=True;integrated security=True;App=EntityFramework">
```

Comment: Thanks @kaushik  it add role in database but after adding roll i want to redirect to list of roles, is it possible to do this ? i get an exception , "Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'data source'. "